# ajax code to display all images from a folder

Tags: ajax, image, directory

Code to read all images from a folder(can read images irrespective of names) is given below:

```
var data1=new Array();
var dir=album_name;
        var fileextension=".JPG";
        $.ajax({
            url: dir,
            async:false,
            success: function (data) {// function to read image files
                $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                    var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///photogallery",""); 
                    data1[j++]=dir+filename;

                });
            }
    });
```

path of album folder is: photogallery/albums/album1 from www directory of localhost.

These code works fine and get all images from that specified folder album1. They only checking the extension is .jpg or not.and retrieve all files having extension .jpg

There would be any problem if this code put in live.

It will produce no output if we change the directory of photogallery to any other folder.
If did like this then should specify the path in the given code:

```
var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///photogallery","");
```

Please help me to clear my doubt.

If it has any problem,please specify the correct method.

Thanks in advance..